# What happens when we dont specify 0dp for layout_width or layout_height when using layout_weight attribute?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have the following code from a project

```
         <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/relative"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/label_friend_count"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="0.6"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_10dp"
                        android:text="@string/lbl_lead_count"
                        android:textColor="@color/color_grey_icon"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_lead_count"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.4"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_10dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/color_323232"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_10dp" />
                 </LinearLayout>
```

Here both the `TextViews` don't specify the width as `0dp` and specify the `layout_weight` attribute with values 0.6 and 0.4, According to the tutorials i have gone through 1st `TextView` with id `label_friend_count` should occupy 60% of the space and 2nd `TextView` with id `txt_lead_count` should occupy 40% of the space. But in this code First `TextView` occupies less space and 2nd `TextView` ocuupies more space... Can anyone tell me how is this possible? Is it because of not specifying `layout_width` as `0dp` and when to use floating point values with `layout_weight`?

This is the Snapshot of my layout

[image: This is the Snapshot of the layout]

Comment: use `weightSum="1"` on your outer parent layout

Comment: No change in layout even if i add weightSum as 1.

Comment: @Android `android:layout_width="0dp"`

Comment: apply `android:layout_width="0"` on your textview this will solve your problem

Comment: Thank u!!! This gives me the desired result... But when do we need to use values less than 1 with `layout_weight`?

Comment: try this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=70-JVroY1Ng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `android:weightSum="1"` to your LinearLayout and use `0dp` width instead of `match_parent` in `TextView` to get your desired result

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/label_friend_count"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="0.6"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_10dp"
                    android:text="@string/lbl_lead_count"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_grey_icon"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_lead_count"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.4"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_323232"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_10dp" />
             </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No change even if i add weightSum.

Comment: Thank u it works!!! Does this mean that `layout_weight` attribute had no effect on this layout? Because my layout changes abruptly when i remove the `layout_weight` attribute!!

Comment: `layout_weight` attribute commonly used when `layout_width` or `layout_height` value is `0dp`. kindly accept my answer if your problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

> [**android:layout_weight**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_weight) Indicates how much of the extra space in the LinearLayout is allocated
>   to the view associated with these LayoutParams. Specify 0 if the view
>   should not be stretched. Otherwise the extra pixels will be pro-rated
>   among all views whose weight is greater than 0.

Set  **`android:layout_width="0dp"`**

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="1">                

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_friend_count"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_10dp"
        android:text="@string/lbl_lead_count"
        android:textColor="@color/color_grey_icon"
        android:textSize="16sp" />


        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_lead_count"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/color_323232"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_10dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this.
You can use the layout_width as wrap_content or 0dp.
The Default weightsum for layout is 1.

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/relative"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/label_friend_count"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="0.6"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_10dp"
                        android:text="@string/lbl_lead_count"
                        android:textColor="@color/color_grey_icon"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_lead_count"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.4"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_10dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/color_323232"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_10dp" />
                 </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```